# method to decide if two strings are anagrams

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash-map

I'm studying with the Cracking the Code Interview book. I'm just looking for some feedback on this method:

C++

```
bool areAnagrams(const char*s1, const char*s2){
    unordered_map <char,int> m1,m2;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < strlen(s1); i++){
        m1[s1[i]] += 1;
    }
    for(size_t j = 0; j < strlen(s2); j++){
        m2[s2[j]] += 1;
    }
    for(auto i = m1.begin(); i != m1.end(); i++){
        if(m2[(*i).first] != (*i).second)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with `return m1==m2;`?

Comment: @MercuryDime: `std::is_permutation()` is \$O(n^2)\$.

Comment: @MercuryDime: Why would `m1==m2` have anything to do with permutations?!?! Anyways, the C++ standard guarantees the complexity of equality testing containers is linear.

Comment: What about spaces? Spaces in the second string don't need to match spaces in the first for it to still be an anagram.

Comment: A much simpler approach would be to sort the characters in each string and then do a string comparison.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Bug

Your algorithm is not quite correct.  For example:

```
areAnagrams("abc",  "abc")  -> true  (correct)
areAnagrams("abc",  "abcd") -> true  (wrong)
areAnagrams("abcd", "abc")  -> false (correct)
```

The problem is that you are checking that the characters in `s1` exist with the same frequency in `s2`.  But there can be characters in `s2` that do not exist in `s1` and you don't check for those.

An easy way to remedy this would be to check that both strings have the same length.  This plus the frequency check you are already doing should ensure that the strings are anagrams.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the bug [JS1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/u/58193) [discovered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/165797), namely that you only check whether all elements of the first string have equal frequency in the second string, there's the question why you are building a complete histogram of both strings. Doing so is inefficient. Instead, increment for one string, and decrement for the other one. The result should be zero.

Your compiler hopefully at least memoizes the result of `strlen` for you, or eliminates even that superfluous extra traversal. If it doesn't, that's a factor of `n` for your algorithms complexity right there. [Shlemiel The Painter](http://wiki.c2.com/?ShlemielThePainter) greets you.

```
bool areAnagrams(const char* s1, const char* s2) {
    std::unordered_map map<char, int>;
    while(*s1)
        ++map[*s1++];
    while(*s2)
        --map[*s2++];
    for(auto&& e : map)
        if(e.second)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

It's probably far more efficient to use a plain array of appropriate size on the stack than a complicated `std::unordered_map` with dynamic allocation. Just beware of plain `char`s signedness.

```
bool areAnagrams(const char* s1, const char* s2) {
    int map[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = {};
    while(*s1)
        ++map[(unsigned char)*s1++];
    while(*s2)
        --map[(unsigned char)*s2++];
    for(auto e : map)
        if(e)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Also, avoid `using namespace std;`. I don't have conclusive evidence you used it, but to be safe, here it is: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721)